# Are spaces mandatory when calling modify() on a DateTime or DateTimeImmutable object?

Tags: php, datetime, language-lawyer

The [documentation about `modify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) shows some examples that always contain a space between the number and its unit:

```
$date->modify('+1 day');
$date->modify('+1 month');
```

Are the spaces mandatory? Does the calls with `+1day` or `+1 day` give the same results?

Example:

```
$now = new DateTimeImmutable();

echo $now->modify('+1day')->format('c');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $now->modify('+1 day')->format('c');
```

I [tried on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/nNGQD) and it gives the same dates, so it looks like spaces are not mandatory, but I'm interested in knowing how this input format is defined by the PHP language. The [Supported Date and Time Formats page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) doesn't give any detail <sup>(1)</sup>.

<sup>(1)</sup>: it has been fixed since: https://github.com/php/doc-en/issues/2674#issuecomment-1674040916

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Supported Date and Time Formats page doesn't give any detail.

The format you are asking about is one of the relative ones, so follow the link to their description, https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php:

> | Format | Description | Examples |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | number space? (unit | 'week') | Handles relative time items where the value is a number. | "+5 weeks", "12 day", "-7 weekdays" |

That question mark there after `space?`, means that the space is indeed optional.

Comment: Thanks, today I learned that this function accept all the formats listed on the [Supported Date and Time Formats page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php): https://3v4l.org/06UB0 It wasn't obvious from the documentation.

Comment: @A.L The documentation does say `in a format accepted by DateTimeImmutable::__construct()`...with a link to that page, which then links to the date and time formats. Do you feel it would be clearer with a direct link to the format page?

Comment: @ADyson I ended up on [“Supported Date and Time Formats”](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), the fact that it begins with 4 links in a bullet list confused me, I only read the text and was more confused. I opened a PR in order to add more examples on the `modify` page: https://github.com/php/doc-en/pull/2673